# GridGain Web Console with Docker: 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, swagger-ui, ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to deploy GridGain Web Console **2020.03.01** on RHEL7 x86_64 with Docker following [documentation here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/deploying-web-console-docker).

However, there is *404 Not Found* error on accessing http://localhost:3000/swagger-ui.html page which is used as  healthcheck. Backend logs show no errors. The last version I'm able to get containers running with is **2019.12.02** (which in fact refuses to show a connected cluster, but that's another issue). Starting with **2020.01.00**, all backend healthchecks fail. That looks suspicious considering that [2020.01.00 releasenotes](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/release-notes/2020.01.00/release-notes_2020.01.00) include updates of io.springfox and swagger-ui-dist.

Besides that, [**2020.03.01** releasenotes](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/release-notes/2020.03.01/release-notes_2020.03.01) say that Console's default port is changed to 8008, but the server still starts on 3000.

Anyone had any luck deploying dockerized Web Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Console consists of **backend** and **frontend**. The **backend** is started on port *3000* which is printed in log, while the **frontend** is started indeed on port *8008* - and you most probably want to use this.

The ***docker-compose.yml*** given on Documentation site maps container's *8008* port to host's *80* port, feel free to replace with any wanted.

Regarding the heathcheck, [/health](https://localhost:3000/health) endpoint is now changed to [this](http://localhost:3000/actuator/health)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying healthcheck url! Both containers are up now, but UI shows no connected agents, even though an agent has authenticated and connected successfully. I'll probably make that a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The Swagger was removed in 2020.01.00 due to security concerns (same GG-26726 issue mentioned in the release notes). You are right to be suspicious, I'll ask right people to update release notes and the docs, sorry about the confusion and thanks for pointing the issue out. Swagger was supposed to be an internal feature for Web Console (WC) developer team only.

As you pointed out, starting with 2020.01.00 the Swagger-based health check won't work. Internally, the WC team uses [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) to wait for backend to start, here's an example from our E2E test suite compose:

```
entrypoint: dockerize -wait http://backend:3000/health -timeout 2m -wait-retry-interval 5s node ./index.js --target=${TARGET:-on-premise}
```

This might work for you too, with some adaptation. You will most likely have to remove "healthcheck" sections from docker-compose.yml too, or modify these, if the "http://backend:3000/health" URL can indeed serve as a direct replacement for the old "http://localhost:3000/swagger-ui.html" URL, which I am not sure about.